# Return string from c++ function pointer invoked from c#

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling, function-pointers, managed, managed-c++

I need to call a c++ callback function from c# that returns a String. When I try with the code below the application crashes hard (with a message saying that it may be due to a corruption of the heap).

Here's the c++ code:

```
static String^ CppFunctionThatReturnsString()
{
    return gcnew String("From C++");
}

void main()
{
    CSharp::CSharpFunction(IntPtr(CppFunctionThatReturnsString));
}
```

And here's the c# code:

```
public class CSharp
{
    private delegate string CppFuncDelegate();

    public static void CSharpFunction(IntPtr cppFunc)
    {
        var func = (CppFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(cppFunc, typeof(CppFuncDelegate));
        func(); // Crash
    }
}
```

Do I have to do some kind of marshaling magic with the string before returning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using function pointers in the first place? Just pass an instance of the delegate to the C# code:

**C++:**

```
static String^ CppFunctionThatReturnsString()
{
    return gcnew String("From C++");
}

void main()
{
    CSharp::CSharpFunction(new CSharp::CppFuncDelegate(CppFuncThatReturnsString));
}
```

**C#:**

```
public class CSharp
{
    private delegate string CppFuncDelegate();

    public static void CSharpFunction(CppFuncDelegate d)
    {
        d();
    }
}
```

I think you may need to put CppFuncThatReturnsString inside a class.

Comment: @Torbjörn Kalin Do not make such changes in the code.
Better point them out to the person who answered

Comment: Obviously, that's the way to do it... Also, this way, I don't have to worry about the returned char* being destructed (in case it's on the stack). Thanks!

Comment: @Coding Mash Why not? My edits do not change the correctness of the answer. I'd say it's like fixing typos/spelling errors.

Comment: @user1775315 The CppFuncThatReturnsString function does not need to be inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [this ten year old page](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=1108).

c++:

```
static const char* __stdcall CppFunctionThatReturnsString()
{
    return "From C++";
}

void main()
{
    CSharp::CSharpFunction(IntPtr(CppFunctionThatReturnsString));
}
```

c#:

```
public class CSharp
{
    private delegate IntPtr CppFuncDelegate();

    public static void CSharpFunction(IntPtr cppFunc)
    {
        var func = (CppFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(cppFunc, typeof(CppFuncDelegate));
        Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(func());
    }
}
```

That is, pass it as an IntPtr and marshal it into a string on the C# side.